# Could anyone explain the CTE in SQL in a clear and concise manner?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Could anyone explain to me what a CTE in SQL is, in a clear and concise manner?

Comment: It is kind of temporary table and working on the result set. Please refer this Microsoft document with example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: I doubt if the programmers who inhabit this space can do better than the technical authors who write the manuals and contribute to the likes of wikipedia. If you have a specific issue on the other hand you are should ask a question on that basis.

Comment: Are you familiar with views? If yes, CTEs are like creating "virtual" views which are valid only for the single SQL statement you are currently writing. They allow you to make complex SQLs more readable and avoid repetition.

Comment: Recursion however is where cte's really become useful.

Comment: @P.Salmon: True, but for a person struggling to understand the basic premise of CTEs, it might make sense to postpone the topic of recursion.

Comment: I disagree that it's a "kind of temporary table" @AnanthMK . A temporary table is an object, a CTE is (as its name states) an **expression**. They have very different "rules" on how they persist and can be referenced. They aren't anything anything alike apart from that both are referenced in the `FROM`.

Comment: CTE or `common table expression` is a result set created from a simple SELECT statement https://learnsql.com/blog/what-is-common-table-expression/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CTE is Common Table Expression.  Think of this as a single query and it will give you a result set.  Now you can use that in a subsequent query without having to have too complex a bunch of garbage all nested.  For example

```
with MyAliasJustManagers as
( select 
         E.EmployeeID,
         E.FirstName as ManagerFirstName,
         E.LastName as ManagerLastName
      from
         Employees E
      where
         E.IsManager = 1
)
-- NOW, you can query with the above sample
select
      E.FirstName,
      E.LastName,
      M.ManagerFirstName,
      M.ManagerLastName
   from
      Employees E
         JOIN MyAliasJustManagers M
            on E.ManagerID = M.EmployeeID
```

You can see the simplicity above.  You can predefine multiple With CTE to be used in the final SQL query, otherwise the above would have looked something like

```
select
      E.FirstName,
      E.LastName,
      M.ManagerFirstName,
      M.ManagerLastName
   from
      Employees E
         JOIN ( select 
                      E.EmployeeID,
                      E.FirstName as ManagerFirstName,
                      E.LastName as ManagerLastName
                   from
                      Employees E
                   where
                      E.IsManager = 1
             ) M
            on E.ManagerID = M.EmployeeID
```

Notice the second has the query embedded within the outer.  If your queries are complex and have many other criteria, it is probably easier to have that stand-alone query as a WITH simplified.  This way you know that one component works without causing confusion being embedded with multiple and figuring out what is causing problems outright.

Answer (score 1):

A CTE (Common Table Expression) is a type of subquery that can be included in a bigger SQL query.

It typically expresses intermediate results that can be further processed by another CTE or by the main query.

The simplest use of a CTE can look like:

```
with a as (select ...) -- we define a CTE named "a"
select * from a;       -- we use the CTE
```

A query can define multiple CTEs, and each one can use a previously defined CTE. For example:

```
with a as (select ...),
     b as (select ...),
     c as (select * from a join b on ...)
select * from c;
```

Finally, even though CTEs conceptually represent intermediate results, the database is not forced to materialize this result, but can do any kind of dirty tricks to compute the final result of the query. In particular, it can internally rewrite the query or it can internally combine multiple CTEs into one without you noticing.